# How to dispose of flash bar in flutter when user disposes of screen?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to find a way to dispose of flash bar ([flash package](https://pub.dev/packages/flash)) when `Navigator.of(context).pop()` is called. When user pops current screen where flash bar is visible it disappears only after its duration time has elapsed.

I tried creating FlashController in screen that displays flash bar, and creating `FlashController` callback function from `showCustomFlashbar()` method where I would assign `FlashController` from `builder` to `FlashController` from screen it is used in.

But let's say I want to use this flash bar in 50 different screens. That's too much copy/paste code each time. Is there a way it can be dismissed universally so that I wouldn't have to do that in every screen.

My custom flash bar:

```
Future<void> showCustomFlashbar(BuildContext context,
    {required String message, Duration duration}) async {

  await showFlash(
      context: context,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      builder: (_, controller) {
        return CustomFlashbar(
          controller: controller,
          message: message,
        );
      });

  return;
}

class CustomFlashbar extends StatelessWidget {
  final FlashController controller;
  final String message;

  const CustomFlashbar(
      {Key? key, required this.controller, required this.message})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flash(
      controller: controller,
      behavior: FlashBehavior.floating,
      position: FlashPosition.top,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      child: FlashBar(
        content: Text(
          message,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How it is used in code:

```
void showTestFlashbar() async {
  await showCustomFlashbar(context, 'This is test flashbar');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `controller.dispose;` in dispose method of stateful widget.

Reference: https://github.com/sososdk/flash/issues/7#issuecomment-619475438